# Mean of following n row Pyspark window

Tags: python, pyspark, window, rows, between

I need to calculate, for each ID and row, the mean of the last 3 periods (excluding the current one (where I would to enter the same value) and managing the case in which the period has no other 3 minor periods).

For example:

INPUT:

| ID | $ | TIME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 20/11/2021 |
| 1 | 200 | 17/11/2021 |
| 1 | 150 | 15/11/2021 |
| 1 | 170 | 10/11/2021 |
| 1 | 130 | 05/11/2021 |
| 2 | 200 | 20/11/2021 |
| 2 | 200 | 17/11/2021 |

OUTPUT:

| ID | $ | TIME | MEAN ($) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | *100* | 20/11/2021 | *(200+150+170)/3 = 173.33** |
| 1 | 200 | 17/11/2021 | **(150+170+130)/3 = 150** |
| 1 | **150** | 15/11/2021 | ... |
| 1 | **170** | 10/11/2021 | ... |
| 1 | **130** | 05/11/2021 | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2 | *200* | 20/11/2021 | *200* |
| 2 | 150 | 17/11/2021 | ... |

Is there a window function to make it? I hope I don't have to use a loop :)
Thank u for ur precious help!

Comment: Why is the mean for row 1 equal to 100? Shouldn't it be (200+150+170)/3 ?

Comment: I wrong... now i have corrected it! thank u

Comment: And the last three rows of each group should remain the same as `$`, am I correct?

Comment: yes, correct! can u help me? :)

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution that uses [window functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Window.html) as well as the [`applyInPandas`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.GroupedData.applyInPandas.html) method, which from Spark 3.0.0 allows to perform Pandas UDFs on each group of a PySpark dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.types import *



# transform column as date
df = df.withColumn('TIME', F.to_date(F.col('TIME'), format='dd/MM/yyyy'))



# define window function to generate moving average
w = Window().partitionBy('ID').orderBy(F.desc('TIME')).rowsBetween(1, 3)



# define function and schema for applyInPandas
def dollars_last_rows(pdf):
  N = 3
  pdf.iloc[-N:]['MEAN_DOLLARS'] = pdf.iloc[-N:]['DOLLARS'].astype('float')
  return pdf

schema = StructType([
  StructField('ID', LongType(), True),
  StructField('DOLLARS', LongType(), True),
  StructField('TIME', DateType(), True),
  StructField('MEAN_DOLLARS', DoubleType(), True)
])



df \
  .withColumn('MEAN_DOLLARS', F.mean('DOLLARS').over(w)) \
  .groupby('ID') \
  .applyInPandas(dollars_last_rows, schema) \
  .show()
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use native [`window`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Window.html?highlight=window#pyspark.sql.Window) analytics functions and [`when and otherwise`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.when.html). This does not use any extra UDFs.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window, Column


data = [(1, 100, "20/11/2021",),
        (1, 200, "17/11/2021",),
        (1, 150, "15/11/2021",),
        (1, 170, "10/11/2021",),
        (1, 130, "05/11/2021",),
        (2, 200, "20/11/2021",),
        (2, 200, "17/11/2021",), ]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ("ID", "$", "TIME",)).withColumn("TIME", F.to_date(F.col("TIME"), "dd/MM/yyyy"))

def mean_dollars() -> Column:
    window_spec = Window.partitionBy("ID").orderBy(F.desc("TIME")).rowsBetween(1, 3)
    sum_preceeding_3 = F.sum("$").over(window_spec)
    count = F.coalesce(F.count("$").over(window_spec), F.lit(0))
    return F.when(count < 3, F.col("$")).otherwise(sum_preceeding_3 / count)

(df.withColumn("MEAN ($)", mean_dollars()).show())
```

### Output

```
+---+---+----------+------------------+
| ID|  $|      TIME|          MEAN ($)|
+---+---+----------+------------------+
|  1|100|2021-11-20|173.33333333333334|
|  1|200|2021-11-17|             150.0|
|  1|150|2021-11-15|             150.0|
|  1|170|2021-11-10|             170.0|
|  1|130|2021-11-05|             130.0|
|  2|200|2021-11-20|             200.0|
|  2|200|2021-11-17|             200.0|
+---+---+----------+------------------+
```